# Create a column vector filled variables dependence upon previous row entry

Tags: matlab

I wish to create a column vector with each row entry dependent upon the above row entry. So as an example:

`A` is an (n x 1) vector and `a_1` is the initial set value.

```
A=[a_1, a_1+a_2, a_2+a_3, ... , a_n-1+a_n]
```

I tried a loop of some variety but I couldn't get it to work.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this -

```
[A(1) ; A(1:end-1) + A(2:end)]
```

Comment: @josh Not sure I got you there. So, did you mean that this worked for you Or something else you tried for yourself that worked Or are you still stuck? If you are still stuck maybe post some sample input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Many thanks Divakar. I made a small change to achieve what I needed. For simplicity I have make a1 = 2 and I have supposed that I would like to have k added on to each next place.

a1=2
A=[a1;zeros(9,1)]
for k=1:10
    A=[A(1:k) ; A(k:end-1) + k]
end

(I am in fact using random variables in my actual work but though this showed the solution better).

Comment: Sorry, I had a bit of a nightmare with not clicking shift-return to do a new paragraph and kept adding my comment before I was finished. Hopefully my reply is understandable?

Comment: @josh Awesome, it sounds like you are set, great!